# Integrals and Fundamental theorem of calculus?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I have several problems like these two, but I've been stuck on them forever, I thought I knew what I was doing, since the fundamental theorem of calculus is just the derivative of f(b)-f(a). Anyways, I have no idea how to actually do this and I've just been using the different theorems and they are all wrong. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUecQ.png)

Comment: Edward Stark, wow, you've been away for a long time... Good to hear from you!

Comment: It is silly to say "the fundamental theorem of calculus is just the derivative of $f(b)-f(a)$".  A _theorem_ is expressed as a sentence --- the kind of thing that can be true of false. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Just as  a reminder, the fundamental theorem of calculus write
$$\frac d {dx}  \int_c^x f(t)\,dt=f(x)$$ Now, using the chain rule $$\frac d {dx}  \int_c^{a(x)} f(t)\,dt=f\big(a(x)\big)\, a'(x)$$ and similarly $$\frac d {dx}  \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t)\,dt=f\big(b(x)\big)\, b'(x)-f\big(a(x)\big)\, a'(x)$$

Do you percieve the logic from the first to the third equation ?